# char array to string convert

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to convert my char array to string and I get some random chars in my result only first time when I'm trying to convert array, on second time when I convert array, string is clean from random chars

How i convert to string

```
String ^text3= gcnew String(data3);
```

Char array

```
-       data3   "37"    char[]
        [0x0]   0x33 '3'    char
        [0x1]   0x37 '7'    char
```

result

```
text3   "377000101095259001064537н" System::String^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it correctly, but String constructor requires NULL-terminated string. So your data3 should have terminating \0 after 2 elements.